# How to date trunc in HANA

Tags: date, hana

I have a query to get the count of buses which travel less than 100 km per day. So I use the query in PostgreSQL

```
     select day,count(*)as bus_count from(

     SELECT date_trunc('hour',start_time)::timestamp::date  as  day,bus_id,sum(distance_two_points) as distance
     FROM public.datatable where start_time >= '2015-09-05 00:00:00' and start_time <= '2015-09-05 23:59:59' 
     group by day,bus_id 
    
    ) as A where distance<=250000 group by day
```

The query returns the result

```
       day                bus_id   distance
       ___               ________  _________
    "2015-09-05 00:00:00"   1       523247
    "2015-09-05 00:00:00"   2       135114
    "2015-09-05 00:00:00"   3       178560
    "2015-09-05 00:00:00"   4       400071
    "2015-09-05 00:00:00"   5       312832
    "2015-09-05 00:00:00"   6       237075
```

So I now want to use this same query (achieving same results) in SAP HANA but there is no date `trunc` function and I also tried

```
 SELECT EXTRACT (DAY FROM TO_DATE (START_TIME, 'YYYY-MM-DD')) "extract"  as  day,
               bus_id, sum(distance_two_points) as distance
         FROM public.datatable 
         where start_time >= '2015-09-05 00:00:00' and start_time <= '2015-09-05 23:59:59' 
         group by day,bus_id 
        
        ) as A where distance<=250000 group by day
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting to a non-datetime data type is usually not a good idea (additional parsing, encoding, semantics...).

Instead use a less granular datetime data type: `daydate` in this case.

```
create column table datatab (start_time seconddate, bus_id int, distance_two_points decimal (10, 2));


insert into datatab values (to_seconddate('05.09.2015 13:12:00'), 1, 50.2);    
insert into datatab values (to_seconddate('05.09.2015 13:22:00'), 1, 1.2);    
insert into datatab values (to_seconddate('05.09.2015 15:32:00'), 1, 24);    

insert into datatab values (to_seconddate('05.09.2015 13:12:00'), 1, 50.2);    

insert into datatab values (to_seconddate('05.09.2015 14:22:00'), 2, 1.2);    
insert into datatab values (to_seconddate('05.09.2015 16:32:00'), 2, 24);    


  select to_seconddate(day) as day,count(*) as bus_count from(

     SELECT to_date(start_time) as day, bus_id, sum(distance_two_points) as distance
     FROM  datatab
     where start_time between '2015-09-05 00:00:00' and '2015-09-05 23:59:59' 
     group by to_date(start_time),bus_id 

    ) as A 
    where distance<=250000 
    group by day;
```

The inner query gives you:

```
DAY         BUS_ID  DISTANCE
2015-09-05  1       75.40   
2015-09-05  2       25.20
```

So, your `seconddate` "start_time" is now aggregated as `daydate` and then converted back to 'seconddate'.

Comment: Sure, this will be slightly faster than to_nvarchar. I guess the documentation is not very accurate here, it says for to_date: "Converts a date string into a DATE data type". I think for date/time types it does a direct conversion, not via string...

Comment: Yes, the documentation is not particularly comprehensive in many aspects. Looking at the function signature shows, that to_date takes all kinds of data types as an input. Another important concern is that you typically don't want a STRING data type when you start with a datetype data type and just want to get rid of the hour-part of it. The expectation would be to still work with a datetime data type.

Comment: @LarsBr. The problem is I need a timestamp witnout timezone and not a daydate.Otherwise I can also extract all seperately and combine them outside the query but that too takes a bit long time.

Comment: Can't see that you specified this anywhere. HANA doesn't cater for timezones in its datetime data types - not sure where the remark about timezones is coming from. The example I gave you delivers precisely what you have specified. Please be more specific on how this is not what you wanted.

Comment: @LarsBr. I edited the question.Now it should be clear I guess

Comment: So, you actually *want* the zeros in the output? If so just re-convert the DAY column into a timestamp (to_seconddate()). I've edited my reply accordingly... Now I understand that it was just a mistake when you talked about time zones - you meant the hours:minutes:seconds part.

Comment: Actually my start_time column is a timestamp and I want to trunc the timestamp upto the hour level.For example if the timestamp is `2017-02-10 10:38:09`  then it should return `2017-02-10 10:00:00`

Comment: Well, that's what you get with the to_seconddate() conversion. The `timestamp` data type in HANA preserves also sub-seconds, which is explicitly *not* what you want.

Comment: @Lars.Br  `select to_seconddate ("start_time") where id=1`.This is the query I executed and the start_time was `'2016-09-01 11:23:19'` and the query also gave the same result.But instead of that I want `'2016-09-01 11:00:00'`to be returned.I think now I am a bit clear

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SERIES_ROUND('2013-05-24', 'INTERVAL 1 YEAR', ROUND_DOWN) "result" FROM DUMMY;

SELECT SERIES_ROUND('04:25:01', 'INTERVAL 10 MINUTE') "result" FROM DUMMY;
```

The SERIES_ROUND from SAP Hana provides similar functionalities as DATE_TRUNC in other vendors.
https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_HANA_PLATFORM/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/435ec476ab494ad6b8409f22abec13fe.html?version=2.0.00

Answer (score 0):

What I prefer is using the seconds_between() or nano100_between() function.

```
select now(), 
       add_seconds(  to_date('1970.01.01', 'YYYY.MM.DD'),
                     round(
                        SECONDS_BETWEEN(
                            to_date('1970.01.01', 'YYYY.MM.DD'),
                            now()
                        )/3600
                     )*3600
       ) 
from dummy;
```

This looks a bit ugly but given the to_date() is calculated just once and not for each row and the seconds arithmetic is close to how Hana stores the value internally, it should be the most efficient of the lot.
Also it is the most flexible, round by second, minute, hour, day,... everything below year is fine.

PS: round() supports all round and truncate options.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your start_time is of some data/time type (e.g. SECONDDATE) you could use

```
...TO_NVARCHAR(START_TIME, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS DAY...
```

Instead of date_trunc... in PostgreSQL

Comment: casting the date into a different data type just to get rid of the hour:minutes part is not the best choice. It requires data copying, formatting and encoding, just to ignore parts of the already present data.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use CAST() conversion function?

```
select 
    cast( now() as date ) myDate
from dummy;
```

Comment: That's the same as to_seconddate() - just more typing ;)